# Attempting to begin modal transition while transition is in progress

Tags: ios, facebook, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to check if a user is logged into Facebook. If they are, I want to transfer them to another view.

The issue I'm having is that `loginViewFetchedUserInfo` and `loginViewShowingLoggedInUser` are both called before the view is actually done loading.

Because of this, when `[self showWelcome:self]` is called, I get a "**attempting to begin modal transition while transition is in progress**" error.

I can't seem to figure out a way to wait until the view is done loading before sending them off to the new view.

```
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {

    // Set flag
    isFirstLoginDone = YES;

    NSLog(@"User is logged in");
}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                        user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    // Check first login
    if(isFirstLoginDone) {
         [self showWelcome:self];
    }

    // clear the flag
    isFirstLoginDone = NO;

}

- (IBAction)showWelcome:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"WelcomeStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , it happens when you present some another viewController while a viewController is being present. For that create a dummy method as below code and fire it with small time intervals.

```
- (IBAction)showWelcome:(id)sender{
   [self someMethod];
}

-(void)someMethod{
    if(self.isBeingPresented){
        [self performSelector:@selector(someMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
    }
    else{
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"WelcomeStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeController"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```